# What is the need of initialising a variable like var x = new Number(5), even we have var y = 5?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 5;
var y = new Number(5);

typeof(x)  //returns number
typeof(y)  //returns object
```

Also:
`(x == y)` is true because x and y have equal values
`(x === y)` is false because x and y have different types

Comment: Indent by four spaces to format code correctly.

Comment: And are you asking what the purpose of the Number constructor is?

Comment: There's absolutely no need for it. That it is made possible by the language does not mean that anyone should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Number is wrapper class that can convert for example string to number.
Because of that "5"+5="55" but Number("5")+Number(5)=10.
It will only assert that adding numbers will occur.

Comment: `Number("5")` and `new Number("5")` are not identical. The OP is asking about use cases for `new Number`.